# Angular How to better use my service

Tags: angularjs

I have a service who is generating the shape of a gallery of pictures.

when i arrive for the first time in the view everything is alright but when i go to another one and come back to the view with the gallery, the service seems to be not called because nothing happens...

Here's the service:

```
'use strict';

angular.module('myApp')
  .service('displayGal', function(){

        var displayGallery = function(){
          var images = document.getElementById('flickr_gallery').children;

        var padding = 10,
            columns = 3,
            leftPosition,
            topPosition;

        for(var i = 1; i < images.length; i++){
            if(i % columns === 0){
                topPosition = (images[i-columns].offsetTop + images[i-columns].offsetHeight) + padding;
                images[i].style.top = topPosition + 'px';
            }else{
                if(images[i-columns]){
                    topPosition = (images[i-columns].offsetTop + images[i-columns].offsetHeight) + padding;
                    images[i].style.top = topPosition + 'px';
                }
                leftPosition = (images[i-1].offsetLeft + images[i-1].offsetWidth) + padding;
                images[i].style.left = leftPosition + 'px';
            }
        }
      }
        window.addEventListener('load', displayGallery, true);
        window.addEventListener('resize', displayGallery, true);
  });
```

and i'm injecting it like that in my controller:

```
angular.module('myApp')
  .controller('MainCtrl', function ($scope, displayGal) {
...
...etc
```

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: This is not the job of a service.  This is a job for a directive.

Answer (score 1):

For a start, this sort of DOM manipulation does not belong in a service. It belongs in a directive.

Secondly, is there a reason you are doing manual DOM manipulation instead of using Angular directives and bindings?

Thirdly (and the real answer to your immediate problem), services are singletons in Angular. The first time they are injected, they get instantiated, and the result is stored for all subsequent injections. Since your service function doesn't return anything, the value of `undefined` will be used for injecting into `MainCtrl`. If you must do this as a service, change to using `.factory()` instead of `.service()` and return a new function every time that will do the work. Then call that function inside your `MainCtrl`.

e.g.

```
angular.module('sainsburysTest')
       .factory('displayGal', function(){
            var displayGallery = function () {
            ...
            };
            return displayGallery;
       });

 angular.module('sainsburysTest')
        .controller('MainCtrl', function ($scope, displayGal) { 
             displayGal();
             ...
        });
```

Though I have to stress again this is not a good idea. Not least because you cannot unregister your event handlers on `window` when you navigate away from that page. This is a quick path to memory leaks.

Whereas, if you do it in a directive, you can listen to the `$scope.$on('$destroy', function () { ... });` event and then remove the event listeners on `window` correctly.

Comment: Thanks Greg for the details, i change it to a factory to fixe it and see what happens but noting happen.

Comment: @tarboosh Did you make sure to return the `displayGallery` function like I suggested? If you `console.log('displayGal = ', displayGal);` as the first line in your `MainCtrl` function, what gets logged?

Comment: the function itself but the images are not well rendered in the view

Comment: @tarboosh What do you mean by "the images are not well rendered in the view"? Have you been investigating how to do this as a directive? That is really the best way to do this, even if you don't yet understand directives. Learning them will tremendously advance your AngularJS skills.

Comment: Thank you for you support on that point i wil definitely try to do as a directives